# Spring MVC: Newbie error. Classnotfound exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Im getting the following `ClassNotFoundException` while trying to run my sample application. It would be great if anyone could point out what Im doing wrong. Thanks!

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.thecafetechno.HelloWorldController] for bean with name '/requestURI.htm' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thecafetechno.HelloWorldController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1138)
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thecafetechno.HelloWorldController
....
```

However, Ive defined `HelloWorldController` in the right place . Here is my dispatcher servlet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolverBean" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
   </bean>
   <bean name="/requestURI.htm" class="com.thecafetechno.HelloWorldController" >
        <property name="processor" ref="processorBean"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="processorBean" class="process.Processor" />
</beans>
```

Comment: is the location of your controller on your classpath?

Comment: @MattWhipple: How do I modify the classpath?

Comment: you should normally let whatever kind of tools(build system/IDE) you're using take care of it for you

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html

Comment: @MattWhipple: Yup, eclipse is handling it for me.All Ive done is to add the jar files im using to the classpath using the IDE

Comment: Eclipse will only help within Eclipse but assuming you're able to produce the right WAR file you should be alright.  I'd check to make sure the file is being added to the WAR file properly, and otherwise you'll need to configure Eclipse accordingly, or more flexibly adopt Gradle/Maven/Ant

Comment: I tried creating a war file from the project and it contains the `HelloWorldController` class that apparently Eclipse cant find. So Im pretty much roadblocked.

Comment: Can Eclipse not find it or the application not find it?  What are you using to build your project?  Is the directory structure properly matching the package structure?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18372/discussion-between-kodeseeker-and-matt-whipple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for you to send that sample application so that I can quickly take a look. It seems to be some issue with how you are buildng application.

Comment: How can I send the code ? I have no means of contacting you here. Do let me know if you know a way out

Comment: Well it is surely a newbie error :)   In dispatcher servlet you mentioned "com.thecafetechno.HelloWorldController" but your actual class is "com.thetechnocafe.HelloWorldController". Typo error !!!!